# Stopping an incense stick from burning

Tags: smell

Sometimes one would like to stop a burning incense stick after a while, before it is completely consumed. If you don't want to keep around it to, for example, put it under water, you can always break it in short pieces. However this can make it more difficult to hold them or to completely burn them afterwards. What are other alternatives to time-out the parfume?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but can't you just cut it right next to where it's burning? I can't imagine that the additional tiny piece you'd now have would prove much of an inconvenience to dispose of.

Comment: Try putting it in airtight container, with very less space. Lack of oxygen will put it out.

Comment: @notthatguy To stop it? But I meant to "program" it to stop after a while.

Comment: @thisisjaymetha But I want it produce smell and then stop without intervention.

Answer (score 10):

This is my hack: a small spring clip.

It is a loose fit on the incense stick, but does not slide on its own because of the shallow angle.

[image]

The burn will extinguish soon.

Comment: Nice colour coordination in the composition. +1 for the action shot. It's holding my attention. Is this an animated GIF? I think I can smell Sandalwood!

Comment: @stan thanks, it is Satya Sai Baba **Nag Champa** Agarbatti – the best.

Comment: Yes, that's it. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 9):

One simple alternative is to put a small wire coil around the stick at the point you want it to stop. This will make the heat dissipate and will lower the coal temperature, preventing the combustion to continue and finishing the process.

[image: Stick with coil]

The picture shows a coil ready for the next short combustion. A tight single loop would suffice.

Answer (score 4):

To stop an incense stick before it has burned to its end so that it can be relit when desired:

Reusable Hack: Fold a piece of aluminum foil a few times into a strip and bend that in half over the glowing end of the glowing tip of the incense for a while.

Two things will extinguish the material: the foil will remove oxygen to snuff the oxidation and the foil will absorb the heat from the ember.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I turn mine upside down in the pot of dirt I’m using.  Usually a plant. I also would use another stick to mold the aluminum foil around then place on said burning stick. I love the metal clip idea: quick, convenient & stylish. Someone should invent that, people will buy anything.